# unistd.h library's getopt() function

Tags: c, function

I'm currently trying to make my own version of getopt() function.
But I do not know how it returns a character type as an int type.

Is there any way I can have a look into the source code of the getopt() function?

Comment: There's no special thing you need to do. int f = 'a'; char c = 'a'; int i = c; It all just works by the implicit conversions.

Comment: the source code is freely available

Comment: "how it returns a character type as an int type" what's the problem with this? Characters are small integers.

Comment: You can find the 'original' `getopt()` source if you search for 'at&t public domain getopt source' — Google shows a number of sites that have copies of it.  It dates back to 1985, so it is written in K&R (pre-standard) C rather than using prototypes, and it worries about `index` vs `strchr`, and it doesn't have a header, but it is otherwise small and tidy.

Comment: `getopt(3)` does not return a `char`, but an `int`. This is the same issue with `getchar(3)` function, as the return values space must be one plus than the values of the `char` type.  So you can get any `char` value, plus `EOF`, which is different than any valid `char` value.  Also, it is defined in `<getopt.h>`, and not in `<unistd.h>` header file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source code of `getopt()` in `glibc` is here: https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/posix/getopt.c

Of course there are more implementations you might look at, but this is probably the most popular one.  Here's another, from FreeBSD: https://github.com/lattera/freebsd/blob/master/lib/libc/stdlib/getopt.c

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `getopt(3)` function is `int` to allow for *an extra value* (apart of all the possible `char`s it returns) to mark the end of options condition.  This extra value is `EOF` (as in `getchar(3)` function) which must be different from any `char` possible value.

To deal with this and the possibility of different **C** compilers implement `char` either as `signed` or `unsigned`, both functions implement the return value as the character value as an `unsigned byte` from `0` to `255` (by mapping all the negative values to positive, this is adding to the negative values the constant `256` ---this is an example, as the language doesn't specify exactly how this is done---, so the negatives go in the range `128..255`), and reserve `EOF` as the value `-1`.

If you are writing a `getopt(3)` function to be integrated in your system's standard c library, just check what value is used for `EOF` (most probable is `-1`) and then implement it so the values returned for your default `char` type don't conflict/overlap with/ it.